# File encryption using Crypto.js with AES cipher algorithm?

Tags: javascript, file, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I have stacked so far with file uploading program on javascript. The code I have wrapped in if() and else statement.

```
   if(filetype.name.match(/(.*?)\.(jpg|gif|doc|pdf|mp3|mp4|avi|txt|png|jpeg|tif)$/)) {
                const formData = new FormData();
                var encryptedfile;
                const url = 'process.php';
                const form = document.querySelector('form');
                form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
    
    
                  const file = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files[0];
    
                    var reader = new FileReader();

And after that, I have written reader.onload function. The code out of that function doesn't see what inside, because of local variables. But the problem not about that 
 

    reader.onload = function() {
                        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(reader.result, "ThisIsPasswordForTheFile" );
         encryptedfile = new File([encrypted], "foo.txt", {
      type: "text/plain"
    
    }); 

    formData.append('files',encryptedfile);
    
                  }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

The problem is const formData = new FormData() doesn't add this encrypted file [image: There is no key and there is no value]

after I send it to the server, and it is successful, but no file the upload folder

fetch(url, {
method: 'POST',
body: formData,
}).then((response) => {
console.log("ok");
// document.location.href = _url+"process.php";
});
});
}

[image: phpcode to process $_POST. And no files in the upload folder]

And I am not really sure about CryptoJS.AES.encrypt code. is this code encrypt right file from document input? `const file = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files[0];`

Please take a look at my whole js code

```
  document.querySelector("#inputGroupFile01").addEventListener("change", function(){
        const reader = new FileReader();
            var filetype =this.files[0]
            if(filetype.name.match(/(.*?)\.(jpg|gif|doc|pdf|mp3|mp4|avi|txt|png|jpeg|tif)$/)) {
                
const formData = new FormData();
                var encryptedfile;
                const url = 'process.php';
                const form = document.querySelector('form');
                form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  const file = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                         reader.onload = function() {
                        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(reader.result, "ThisIsPasswordForTheFile" );
         encryptedfile = new File([encrypted], "foo.txt", {
      type: "text/plain"
    });
    formData.append('files',encryptedfile);
                  }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    
                  fetch(url, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData,
                  }).then((response) => {
                        console.log("ok");
                  });
                });
                }
        else{
    alert("please choose another one!");
    
        }
   
    });
```

Comment: Plz, don't put * in your code example - it makes it unreadable and invalid

Comment: @Endless thanks, I'll fix it